# Add Two Controls in a Table Cell not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

Hi I am trying to add two controls into a table cell the code is below. Unfortunately the hyperlink is always outside the table cell, whilst the label is inside. Individually they are working fine but together not so good, could somebody help me please.

```
Dim iCell As New TableCell

Dim lbl As New Label
lbl.Height = Unit.Pixel(100)
lbl.Width = Unit.Pixel(150)
lbl.Style.Add("padding", "5px")
lbl.Style.Add("border-radius", "10px")
lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
lbl.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(1)
lbl.BorderColor = Color.Black

lbl.Font.Size = 9
lbl.Text = "Event: " & dt.Rows(y).Item("eventname")    
lbl.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(dt.Rows(y).Item("roomcolor"))

Dim hyp As New HyperLink
hyp.Font.Size = 9
hyp.Text = "Modify"
hyp.NavigateUrl = "modify.aspx"

iCell.Controls.Add(lbl)
iCell.Controls.Add(hyp)

iCell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top
tRow.Cells.Add(iCell)
```

Comment: Could you share the rendered HTML?

Comment: And the rest of the code that creates the table. Remove stuff that's not needed.